# Quarkus " Running the application" Tutorial

Tags: quarkus

I try to follow the tutorial for the First Application of Quarkus. 
When I try to run this command: `./mvnw compile quarkus:dev:`
I've the following error:

> The specified path could not be found. "D" is not recognized as an
>   internal or external command, an executable program or a batch file.
>
> The specified path could not be found.
>
> Exception during "DownloadFile" call with "2" argument (s): "Exception during a WebClient request." In line: 1 car: 282
>
> - ... pe] :: Tls12; $ webclient.DownloadFile ('https://repo.maven.apache.org/ma ...
> - CategoryInfo: NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
> - FullyQualifiedErrorId: WebException
>
>   Error: cannot find or load the main class org.apache.maven.wrapper.MavenWrapperMain"

Comment: This has nothing to do with quarkus. Apparently you did not correctly download the maven wrapper.

Comment: Not sure if it's a typo in your question, but the command is `quarkus:dev` and not `quarkus:dev:`, notice the extra colon at the end.

Comment: The problem was used the command prompt of Windows instead the Linux Command Line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was used the command prompt of Windows instead the Linux Command Line.